# Select a data which is equal to another row's/column's data

Tags: sql, database

I'm new to SQL and I tried this.
Here is my table:

```
person_id | parent_id | name    
-----1--------------0----------Steve    
---- 2 -----------  1--------- Joe    
-----3------------- 2--------  Monica    
---- 4 ------------ 2-------   Ted
```

The relationship with these numbers: Joe is Steve's son, so Joe's `parent_id` is equal to his dad's (Steve) `person_id`. Monica and Ted is Joe's children. So, their `parent_id` is equal to their father's `person_id`.

I'm trying to create sql query for this output:

```
-------------------------
| Steve | Joe  | Monica |
-------------------------
| Steve | Joe  | Ted    |
-------------------------
```

I tried this SQL query but it's illogical.

```
SELECT name FROM child,parent where parent.parent_id=child.child_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select y1.name, y2.name, y3.name
From yourTableName y1, yourTableName y2, yourTableName y3
Where y1.person_id = y2.parent_id
And y2.person_id = y3.parent_id
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a self-join:

```
select t.name, tp.name, tgp.name
from mytable t join
     mytable tp
     on tp.person_id = t.parent_id join
     mytable tgp
     on tgp.person_id = tp.parent_id;
```